# Set dynamic width and height of item in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am working on a android project in which I am using `Recyclerview` with`gridlayoutmanger` and Items are Images. I want to display four items in single row so I have set `spancount` to 4 and a gap of 2dp is set between each item with `Itemdecoration`.

```
ItemOffsetDecoration itemDecoration = new ItemOffsetDecoration(getContext(),R.dimen.offset);
fRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);

GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(),4);
```

Each Item height and width are currently 90dp.

Item.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="90dp"
android:layout_height="90dp"
android:id="@+id/imagevideo_layout"
>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/image_video_pic"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Problem is as I am fixing the height and width of item, in some devices due to the screen size differences there is more gap between each item.And in some devices items are overlapping because of small screen sizes.I need only 2dp and only 4 items in single row for all the screen sizes. Is there any way to do this? Is it possible to dynamically set the `relativelayout`s height and width depending on the screen size? I have searched in SO, questions are on setting the `spancount` dynamically by fixing the height and width of each item, but I need reverse of it.

Comment: You need to rework this, there are a number of options like `weights` that would make this much better than using set sizes.

Comment: Thank you for responding, Any link regarding `weights`?

Comment: My apologies, quickly read through everything. Don't set the width if you are using spans with a GridLayout like that. Just use match_parent and let the GridLayoutManager handle scaling to fit the spans. Weights don't work with GridLayouts, since the spans are handled explicitly already.